# async/promise with multiple api calls

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, axios

I kind of understand the differences between callbacks, promises and async await, but I'm not quite sure how to apply this to my problem.

I stripped away a lot of the code, but basically I have an app running with an endpoint that needs to execute 3 functions (maybe I need a 4th?) and also send a "res.end()" within 3 seconds. The 3 functions are dependent on each other. Do I need to chain these functions? My main() seems completely wrong.

- deleteRule() has to run and finish first
- createRule() must run after deleteRule() has completed
- orderRule() must run after createRule() has completed

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

        async function deleteRule() {
            axios.delete(DeleteURL, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
            .then(response => {
                let deleteRes = response.data
                console.log(deleteRes)
            })
        }

        const list = './jsons/list.json'

        async function createRule() {
            fs.readFile(list, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err
                var thestuff = JSON.parse(data)
            
            axios.post(CreateURL, thestuff, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
            .then(response => {
                let createRes = response.data
                console.log(createRes)
            })
        })
        }

        async function orderRule() {
            axios.put(usOrderURL, theOrder, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
            .then(response => {
                let orderRes = response.data
                console.log(orderRes)
            })
        }

        async function main() {
            const deleteListResult = await deleteRule();
            const createListResult = await createRule();
            const orderListResult = await orderRule();
        }

        main();

        // res.end must finish in 3 seconds from the initial post on the first line
        res.end() 

    })
```

Comment: The three first functions are declared as `async`, but use don't `await`. Then `async` isn't of much use. Just `return` the promise returned by the `axios.xxxx().then()` calls.

Comment: ...or use `await` on axios calls and return that result. You probably also need to `await main()` and make the callback `async`.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the res.end() finishes before the 3 functions + main() ? I have it working now, but I'm going over 3 seconds for everything to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then()` calls return promises, but you don't do anything with them. You should either `await` them, or `return` them.

Since you declared your functions as `async`, make use of `await` in them -- that is the whole point of the `async` keyword:

```
async function deleteRule() {
    let response = await axios.delete(DeleteURL, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent});
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}
```

Make a similar change to the other two rule-functions.

Comment: I have it working now, but my res.end() is getting sent after 3 seconds. Is there a way to send res.end() while the other functions are still working?

Comment: Sure there is, but looking at your code, `res.end()` is executed immediately, unless you have other code that is waiting for promises to resolve, but the promise returned by your `main()` call is not awaited, so `res.end()` executes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import fs from 'fs-extra'

const list = './jsons/list.json'

async function deleteRule() {
    const response = await axios.delete(DeleteURL, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
    const deleteRes = response.data

    console.log(deleteRes)

    return deleteRes
}
async function createRule() {
    const data = await fs.readFile(list, 'utf-8')
    const theStuff = JSON.parse(data)
    const response = await axios.post(CreateURL, theStuff, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
    const createRes = response.data
    
    console.log(createRes)

    return createRes
}
async function orderRule() {
    const response = await axios.put(usOrderURL, theOrder, {auth: auth, httpsAgent: agent})
    const orderRes = response.data
    
    console.log(orderRes)

    return orderRes
}

router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
    const deleteListResult = await deleteRule();
    const createListResult = await createRule();
    const orderListResult = await orderRule();

    // res.end must finish in 3 seconds from the initial post on the first line
    res.end() 
})
```

Comment: deleteRule() runs, but then I get "(node:386269) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function"

Comment: actually, I was using fs..switched to fs-extra and it appears to be working now. I'm going over the 3 seconds for the res.end() though.